# Как посчитать сумму с помощью рекурсии в SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

**Есть задача:** За каждую 1000р в клиент получает 1 бонус. Если потратит к примеру 3400р - получит 3 бонуса, а 400р суммируются к следующей покупке. Есть таблица покупок (*id клиента, дата и время, Сумма покупки*).
**Необходимо с помощью рекурсии вычислить количество бонусов, полученных за каждую покупку.**

**Решение с помощью оконных функций:**

```
SELECT ID, DAY, VALUE, (LAG(comm_sum, 0,0) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DAY ASC)) - (LAG(comm_sum, 1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DAY ASC)) AS CAHSBACK FROM (SELECT ID, DAY, VALUE, 
(SUM(VALUE) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DAY ASC))/1000 AS comm_sum FROM task3)AS a;
```

Было:
[image: Было:]

Стало: [image: Стало:]

**Как получить тот же результат, только с помощью рекурсии?**

Comment: Рекурсия в задаче НЕ НУЖНА. То есть вообще. Даже если её туда ногами запинать - она всё равно не будет ничего делать, просто поприсутствует.

Comment: Так вам для *Microsoft SQL Server* нужно решение или для *PostgreSQL?*

Comment: Да хоть для MySQL) Это тестовая задача